# Access VBA: Copy single record to memory

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am converting an amalgamation of Excel VBA worksheets to an Access database. As seen too often, Excel was used as a database, and converting all data to Access Tables was very easy.

Now however comes getting the VBA forms and (object) modules to work again. I think I need to do this using the **Recordset2** objects, however I want to be sure I am doing this the right way.

1. Always open the database read-only.
2. Copy, not link, one complete record to VBA application memory.
3. Use input data from user and data from record to CHANGE some data in this memory (record)... (or not if the user has no data)
4. Pass the record in memory, changed or unchanged, to the next step in 
   the process.

Am I on the right track with Recordset2?

Comment: This is literally what subforms are used for

Comment: You probably need a domain class which you can pass around function.

Comment: To work with database records, the [DAO.Recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-object-dao) object is fine (Recordset2 has some additions like recordset in a field, but they shouldn't be used cause they hide the data structure), but be aware that there is an [ADODB.Recordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) too.

Comment: Good thought on not using Excel as database, but`Ms Access`has its limits too. I would recommend a RDBMS like Sql Server, MySQL, Postgres, ..., But try access forms, as they provide databinding to controls out-of-the-box and provide the famous subforms.

Comment: And if converting sheets to tables was easy, usually, your data model is poor, what should be fixed first (read about "database normalization")!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I looked up database normalization thank you, mostly the data was good - but I will be mindful of it while working on it. 

I will also look at Excel Forms but we were already using a pretty sophisticated UI which I would not expect to be a good fit for Access Forms.

Finally I am beginning to think I should maintain the current datastructures used in the Modules. Replacing the Excel Worksheet "get" functions with a Recordset-Query "get" function.

Comment: :Net UI? That would be an important info (add to question!). RDBMS server is not an option? Then have a look at SQLite (filebased as access, but less restrictions). Be aware that you shouldn't have office db drivers (ODBC/OLE) of different bitness on same OS!

Comment: @ComputerVersteher no, just an Excel VBA Form. Being able to reuse all VBA forms and VBA modules is key to making the migration to Access within budget - all stuff seems to work immediately as expected, apart from the data retrieval obviously.

Comment: How did the Userforms retrieved the data before? Do the same. If a range is needed you can easily create a temp range from a recordset with [Range:CopyFromRecordset](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.range.copyfromrecordset):for an intermediate solution.

Comment: I had a Class Module (one instance per worksheet) that takes 2 strings as input, usually the unique id and the column name and converts to row# and column# (the object builds index to not search twice). After this class module is done all data used is stored in data structures, and no more Excel is involved, just VBA modules built on months of laboratory measurements and modelling. Output is pdf report and .xml file. So I am just rewriting this object module from Excel to Access